# Grep and Copy - Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to grep, copy, and rename the files copied in the destination. 
So, basically I want to look in a directory for a file that contains a certain string, and copy those files when I find a match using grep and rename them once copied. 
I've been reading a lot but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's my script

```
for file in $(grep -R 'myname' /searchdirectory)
do
cp -t $file /destinationfolder
done
```

This doesn't seem to work. Once I figure this out, then I need to figure out how to rename. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: if you want to do recursive searches and still get the fullpaths, `find` might be a better idea than `grep`

Comment: you need to add `-l` argument to grep to get the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. On most modern systems you can use xargs:

```
grep -l --null "$pattern" "$srcPath" |
    xargs -0 -I{} cp {} "$destPath"
```

On any POSIX compliant system you can use `find`:

```
find "$srcPath" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -q "$pattern" {} \; \
    -exec cp {} "$destPath" +
```

The two things wrong with your approach are:

1. You need the `-l` flag to `grep`.
2. You aren't accounting for whitespace and glob expansion on the command substitution, which could be a nightmare.

Comment: I managed to copy the files, now how to I print the files that were copied. Or how do I echo the copied files? I also need to change the extension of the files that were copied. Here's what I'm using:    grep -l -r -i -z 'stringsearch' /sourcedirectory | xargs -i{} cp -p {} /destination

Comment: Try `xargs -i bash -c 'cp {} destination;echo {}'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 1-liner for you:

```
ls | grep 'pattern' | xargs -i cp {} /path/to/destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -l` instead of simple `grep` command.

You are using simple `grep` command and it lists both the filename as well as output. But if you use `-l` option then it lists only file names and then you can copy them in `for` loop.

```
for file in $(grep -l -R 'myname' /searchdirectory)
do
cp -t $file /destinationfolder
done
```